# ASP.NET MVC 3 Logic for dynamically generated dropdown controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form that I generate dynamically, based on the amount of rows in an Excel file that I upload. Where can I add logic that looks through the Description string and sets the dynamically generated dropdownlist to a specified value, based on text in the Description?
I want to add a list of checks, such as:
if "blabla" is in the Description string, set dropdownlist value to 4.

Do I have to do this in Javascript? Cause that doesn't feel that clean to me. I'd prefer my business logic be handled in my Controller, but I'm not sure how that would go in this design.

My code looks like this:

Preview page, which basically just links to my Editor Template named Transaction:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Preview", "Import", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table border="1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Transactions, new { Categories = Model.Categories })
    </table>
    <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Opslaan in database" />
}
```

In this Editor Template transaction, I display some static data, and a textbox and dropdownlist for each row in the Excel that I have previously uploaded in another page:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 40px; padding: 5px; background-color: @CurrencyHelper.GetCurrencyColor(Model.Amount)" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">@Html.Raw(CurrencyHelper.GetCurrency(Model.Currency, Model.Amount))
    </td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 5px;">@Model.DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">@Model.Description
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ShortDescription)
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, new SelectList(ViewData["Categories"] as IEnumerable<Category>, "CategoryId", "Name"))
    </td>
</tr>
```

My controller, which enters the data in the View Model:

```
//Attach unique Transactions and Categories to ViewModel
var viewModel = new ImportViewModel()
{
     Transactions = uniqueTransactions.ToList(),
     Categories = categoryRepository.GetCategories().OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Static Binding**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to the Training Courses...";
            List objcourses = new List();
            objcourses.Add("Asp.Net");
            objcourses.Add("MVC");
            objcourses.Add("WCF");
            objcourses.Add("WPF");
            objcourses.Add("C#.Net");
            ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(objcourses);
            return View();
        }
    }

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
Index
@using(@Html.BeginForm(“Index”,”Home”,FormMethod.Get)) {
Courses List; @Html.DropDownList(“Courses“)
}
```

**Dynamic Binding**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();
            var GenreLst = new List();
            var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
                           orderby d.Genre
                           select d.Genre;
            GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(GenreLst);
            return View();
        }
    }
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
Index

@using(@Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Get)) {

Courses List; @Html.DropDownList("Courses")
}
```